# AngularStrap Popover - data placement is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

For me the **data-placement="auto"** option is not working in AngularStrap (v2.3.5), when I use a html data-template. But when I fill the popover with a data-content property, the dynamic placement seems to work very well.

Works:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-placement="auto" bs-popover="popover">Click to toggle popover
  <br>
  <small>(using an object)</small>
</button>
```

Does not work

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" title="{{popover.title}}" data-template-url="popover/docs/popover.demo.tpl.html" data-placement="auto" data-auto-close="1" bs-popover>Custom Popover
</button>
```

Maybe do you have any hints for me ?

Thanks and best regards !

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: the popover always opens at one position, even if there is not enough space

Answer (score 0):

use data-placement="auto left" or data-placement="auto anyother direction" single auto will not work